# Will this function call be optimized by g++?

Tags: c++, optimization, g++, function-call

I have the following situation:

```
void function(params)
{
  #ifdef _MULTIPLAYER
    if (isConnected)
    {
      if (isClient)
      {
        requestFunctionRemotely(params)
        return;
      }
      else if (isServer)
      {
        call realFunction(params) remotely on client;
      }
    }
  #endif

  realFunction(params);
}

realFunction(params)
{
  ...
}
```

With this situation I'm able to build my project either with single player instance or with multiplayer.

This approach has been used because `function(params)` is called all around my code, so in this way I just attach to the lowest possible level without having problems.

I had to split the `function` and `realFunction` because remote responses received by clients must be executed through `realFunction` to avoid loops (I could change the function prototype to add a flag but I would break a lot of code).

My concern is related to performance when disabling the `_MULTIPLAYER` define. I have A LOT of `function(params)` and I'll call them thousand of times. I'll have to use this approach for all of them. Will g++ optimize away the double call when it will find

```
function(params) {
  realFunction(params);
}
```

to

```
function(params) {
  // body of realFunction
}
```

and there is way to force it in every similar situation?

Just as a hint: I currently use the `-O2` flag

Comment: Have you tried looking at the disassembly when compiling with -03 ?

Comment: If `realFunction` and `function` are in the same translation unit, then yes, almost certainly.  Did you try it?

Comment: 1. Repeat after me: "I am not smarter than the compiler. I will not try to out optimize the compiler. I will not worry about performance at the compiler optimization level until my application becomes too slow". 2. Goto 1

Comment: Yes, the actually are in the same class. I'm trying to understand something in assembly file but it's quite long and I'm not much practical so in the meanwhile I asked here ;)

I guess it won't be optimized with -O0 though, am I right?

Comment: @John3136: you are absolutely right. That's my main principle too but this sort of pattern will take long time to be implemented all around my code, that's why I want to be sure to avoid any performance before doing it. Otherwise I'll try to find a better solution (like having a single player class and a multiplayer copy of it to exchange them). It's something that must run on mobile devices and I'm already pushing it near to limits..

Comment: "I'll call them thousands of times" – actually just thousands, as in like 7000 or 82000? That's unlikely to be enough to make an extra function call even perceivable. This kind of overhead only gets critical if it's many _millions_ of times, or if you mean e.g. thousands of times _per frame_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be sure you could invert your pattern and use a template parameter. That way you are sure the compiler will remove the `if (false)` at compile time.

```
template <bool isMulti>
void Function(params) 
{ 
    if (isMulti)
        MultiFunction();

    // real function code
} 

void MultiFunction(params) 
{  }
```

Note:

If working with a class, you could move up the template parameter to the class for concision.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say, but this should usually be optimized (you can never be sure and the best you can do is giving it some hints, e.g. by using `inline`, but the compiler usually tries to find the best solution itself (also based on "optimize size" vs. "optimize speed", while ignoring your hints (they're no MUST DO for it)).

The probably best (and foolproof) solution would be writing the code in a way that avoids this competely, e.g. something like this:

```
type function(params)
{
#ifdef _MULTIPLAYER
    if(client)
    {
        // call server
    }
    else
#endif
    { // this bracket will be ignored, but saves adding another `#ifdef..#endif` block just to close it again below
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```